# Optimized distribution of events to dates

Tags: algorithm, optimization

My problem is to find the best distribution of a number k of events on 3 evenings. For example k=8 events should be equally distributed on these 3 evenings:

- Evening 1: Event A, B, C
- Evening 2: Event D, E, F
- Evening 3: Event G, H

On the other side I have a group of people who have to go to different events like:

- Person 1: Event A, E, F
- Person 2: Event B, E, H
- Person 3: Event A
- ...

The question is: How can I find the best distribution of the events to the evenings so that the number of rides for the people is minimized?

For the example above, I know that there are 560 different possibilities to distribute the 8 events on the 3 evenings.
I could brute force them and compare the number of required rides but hoped to find a better alternative.

Comment: What is "a ride"? A trip to an event (and back)? If you have 2 events on one evening, does that mean 2, 3, or 4 rides? Are some events at the same time? And how do you want to minimize rides? Is one person having three rides better or worse than two persons having two rides each? How are the constraints? From your example, it does not seem like you have to distribute all events, and also can use events twice.

Comment: Ah, now I get it (I think). The events per person are given, and you search the best distribution of events to evenings such that people can share rides to events.

Comment: Hey tobias_k, thanks for your comment and sorry for the misunderstanding. A ride means a trip to the event and back.
It was not planned that people can share rides. It's only about the number of evenings someone has to drive to the location.
Like in the example for person 1 it would be great if all events A, E and F would be in the same evening (1 trip). And the worst case if they were all on different evenings (3 trips).

Answer (score 2):

This is equivalent to hypergraph partitioning with the connectivity objective (λ - 1). The nodes of the hypergraph are the events. The hyperedges correspond to the people, with each hyperedge connecting the events that the corresponding person has to attend.

There's a vast literature on hypergraph partitioning and a good number of implementations. I'd start with [KaHyPar](https://github.com/SebastianSchlag/kahypar).